# Scroll up div on clicks with animation by jQuery (simple jquery code only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to scrollup a div on click, with delay or animation (which I can eazily add). I am trying to do this by jquery. My divs get a black border but dont scroll up on clicks. Following is the code snippet:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    div {
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div').click(function() {
            //alert("hello");
            $(this).css('border', '3px solid black');
            $(this).animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 'fast');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id=div1 style="background:yellow"></div>
    <div id=div2 style="background:green"></div>
    <div id=div3 style="background:red"></div>
    <div id=div4 style="background:yellow"></div>
    <div id=div5 style="background:purple"></div>
    <div id=div6 style="background:orange"></div>
    <div id=div7 style="background:gray"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `slideUp` if you want to decrease the `height` of the element and hide it eventually:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).css('border', '3px solid black').slideUp();
});
```

> Hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/05yqqcea/

**EDIT**

If you want to scroll current `div` to top:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).css('border', '3px solid black');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).position().top
    }, 'fast');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/05yqqcea/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to scroll the body not div, try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/ffLw2tw3/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').click(function () {
        //alert("hello");
        $(this).css('border', '3px solid black');
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);
    });
});
```